# Apache2 Server Refused To Connect

Tags: apache, google-chrome

I'm new to web development and am attempting to teach myself to build web applications. I have succeeded in setting up an Apache 2 web server on Google Cloud as I am able to access the Debian Default Page on both iOS Safari and Windows Edge through my server's ephemeral External IP.

However when I attempt to visit through Chrome on my PC I am presented with:

```
`INSERT IP ADDRESS HERE Refused To Connect`.
```

I attempted to whitelist the IP in Windows Firewall inbound connections but that did not help at all. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If I understand this correctly, you are trying to access your Google Cloud server from Chrome but getting this error. Does Chrome have a proxy configured?

Comment: Thanks Mikkel. I was trying to access my Apache Server running on a Google Compute Engine VM Instance. Earlier I was trying access through visiting the direct external IP address. After posting my question I mapped a domain I own to the IP of my server and was able to connect without any further problems. As this was my end goal, I consider my problem solved.

Comment: ok good work @pinglock!